# how to find (WLAN)-devices with a Node-App?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I am working on my first Node-App, which I want to connect to two Raspberrys and then control them. Like turn on and off an motion detector or start a webcam. 
I have looked around and saw that people mentioned to make the Raspberry to an web server and then connect it. 
But I don't really understand how that works.

So can anyone tell me **how I can find a device** (the pi's are connect to the WLAN and have a static IP) **via an Node-App**, e.g. with a search feature or so?
And **can I control more then one Raspberry with one App** and **make the them settings on both devices at the same time?**

Comment: You could create a node app(web server) that would run on each RPi and listen on port 80 and control the sensors etc. Then you could create another app on your PC that would try to connect to every IP in given range e.g. 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255 using *request* npm module. Successful response means there's RPi. Sounds simple :)

Comment: hey thanks for the advice. I us request-ip module to check the the address, but the only thing/device I get is "::1" (I run to on each raspberry an node-app, and another one on my computer). when I tried to do the same from one of the RaPi's, than I get the IP from my computer. But the is only the result I get back as a return value. I couldn't figure out how the find the raspberry's..I even tried to make them remotely accessible to see if that makes a difference, but that didn't work either. So now, I get this result that I don't understand, don't know what to do with and I can't reach them.

Answer (score 0):

To get your ip you could use something like this

```
'use strict';

var os = require('os');
var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
Object.keys(ifaces)
    .forEach(function (ifname) {
        var alias = 0;

        ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
            if ('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal !== false) {
                // skip over internal (i.e. 127.0.0.1) and non-ipv4 addresses
                return;
            }

            if (alias >= 1) {
                // this single interface has multiple ipv4 addresses
                console.log(ifname + ':' + alias, iface.address);
            } else {
                // this interface has only one ipv4 adress
                console.log(ifname, iface.address);
            }
            ++alias;
        });

    });
```

This outputs following in my case

```
VirtualBox Host-Only Network 192.168.56.1
Ethernet 192.168.0.101
```

Ethernet is what you want simply extract the ip part of the string

Now you need this part of ip `192.168.0.`

```
var ping = require ("net-ping");
var ipString = '192.168.0.';
var i = 1;
var session = ping.createSession();

doPing()
function doPing() {
    if (i > 254) return;

    var ip = ipString + i;
    i++;

    session.pingHost (ipString + i, function (error, target) {
        if (error){
            if (error instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError){
                console.log (target + ": Not alive");
                doPing();
            }
            else{
                console.log (target + ": " + error.toString ());   
                doPing();         
            }
        } else {
            console.log (target + ": Alive");
            doPing();
        }
    });
}
```

By now you know all devices that responded to ping so you can use `request` module to try to connect to web server if there's any running on the device.

Each ping takes a second or 2 so be patient.

This is far from perfect but should work.
I hope it helps

Comment: hm, the things is... I know my IP-Adress because I set the Pi's to an static IP. </br>But your example show's me that my Pi has more then that. Two IPv4 and two IPv6 addresses. So now I know, with the request ip-module I get the wlan ipv6-adresse from the Pi. Which both Pi's seem to have the same address.</br></br> But anyway, I didn't plan to set the address in the code. My plan was more to include a search in my app, that give's me a list of available devices in the network. So that a user, who has not much programming or technical skills can add different devices by him self.